# pandas read_csv Fails on Large String

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Python 3.7
pandas 0.24.2

Within a Python script, I am loading a zip of many CSVs from a remote server. I am then reading a subset of these CSVs to utf-8 strings, after which I attempt to read each CSV string into a dataframe using `.read_csv()`. Attempts to carry out this action are failing. For a single string:

```
large_string = '"num","domain_name",...,"clientTransferProhibited","","","";'

df = pd.read_csv(large_string, sep=',', engine='python')
```

**Expected**: return a dataframe and run rest of script.
**Observed**: when run from terminal, all of `large_string` gets printed to the console and then the script ends (i.e. does not complete other code, but no error messages). When run in PyCharm, same thing happens, but I also see that it is stalling out down the pandas stack:

`pandas`>`io`>`parsers`>`common.py`

on line 427:
`f = open(path_or_buf, mode, errors='replace', newline="")`

In PyCharm debug, within the `common.py` frame, I am able to see that the exception `Error 63 File name too long` is being thrown (although for some reason this exception never gets printed to console).

What is going on here? Is `read_csv` misinterpreting my data as a filepath? How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`read_csv` was, in fact, misinterpreting the data as a file path.

The solution is to convert the string to a text buffer, which is itself passed to `read_csv`:

```
import io

large_string = '"num","domain_name",...,"clientTransferProhibited","","","";'

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(large_string), sep=',', engine='python')
```

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution is to use **split**:

```
 df = pd.DataFrame([x.split(',') for x in large_string.split('\n')])
```

Comment: This partially works. The catch is that my data has a header row, and this puts the headers as the first row, which isn't such a big deal on its own, but this has the add'l effect of messing up the column type inferences done by pandas.